# a.map is not a function error nvd3 with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to use my data object along with `ng-repeat` with `nvd3` to dynamically create multiple charts.

In my controller, my data for my `$scope` looks like this:

```
$scope.data_costByScn = [
  {
    "key": "K1204", 
    "values": [
      {
        "key": 1420070400000, 
        "values": 317747.6403421797
      }, 
      {
        "key": 1422748800000, 
        "values": 317747.6403421797
      }, 
      {
        "key": 1425168000000, 
        "values": 317747.6403421797
      }
    ]
  }, 
  {
    "key": "test", 
    "values": [
      {
        "key": 1420070400000, 
        "values": 106334.27370394728
      }, 
      {
        "key": 1422748800000, 
        "values": 106334.27370394728
      }, 
      {
        "key": 1425168000000, 
        "values": 106334.27370394728
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and then in my html, I use `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="report-tile" ng-repeat="data in data_costByScn">
        <nvd3 options="options_scn_cst_compare" data="data"></nvd3>
    </div>
</div>
```

when I do that, I get an error in the console that says:

```
TypeError: a.map is not a function
    at nv.d3.min.js:8
    at a.utils.state.g (nv.d3.min.js:2)
    at a.utils.state.update (nv.d3.min.js:2)
    at SVGSVGElement.<anonymous> (nv.d3.min.js:8)
    at d3.min.js:3
    at H (d3.min.js:1)
    at Array.ka.each (d3.min.js:3)
    at Array.b (nv.d3.min.js:8)
    at Array.ka.call (d3.min.js:3)
    at Object.updateWithData (angular-nvd3.js:259)
```

if I don't use ng-repeat and do it like this, the chart renders:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="report-tile">
        <nvd3 options="options_scn_cst_compare" data="data_costByScn"></nvd3>
    </div>
</div>
```

for some reason it won't render with `ng-repeat` thought, I'm guessing my data object isn't formatted correctly but not exactly sure...

Comment: whoops...made a typo...corrected it..

Answer (score 1):

In the second case which displays the chart:

```
<nvd3 options="options_scn_cst_compare" data="data_costByScn"></nvd3>
```

`data_costByScn` is an array of objects.

In the other hand, in the first case with `ng-repeat`

```
<div class="report-tile" ng-repeat="data in data_costByScn">
    <nvd3 options="options_scn_cst_compare" data="data"></nvd3>
</div>
```

`data` is just an object, since `ng-repeat` iterates on all elements of `data_costByScn`.

For instance, if your chart is a multiBarChart, it will expect an array of *series*. 
In order to have several distinct charts, you can add brackets `[` and `]` around the `data` value. This way each multiBarChart will have an array of 1 element:

```
<div class="report-tile" ng-repeat="data in data_costByScn">
    <nvd3 options="options_scn_cst_compare" data="[data]"></nvd3>
</div>
```